# "Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io" in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

When running the following Python Panda code:

```
    xl          = pd.ExcelFile(dataFileUrl)
    sheets      = xl.sheet_names
    data        = xl.parse(sheets[0])
    colheaders  = list(data)
```

I receive the ValueError:

```
Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io
```

The file is for sure an excel file, no doubt about that.

What is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(dataFileUrl, engine='xlrd')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it was because the code that generated dataFileUrl produced a list with only one element in it. Changing to dataFileUrl[0] fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your file path as:

```
#Read and write to excel
dataFileUrl = R"D:\\real_names.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(dataFileUrl)
```

it will possibly work. I have tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  I ended up using the following code to get the excel file I needed from a Github repository into a Pandas dataframe:

```
excel_url = R"https://github.com/user/repository/blob/master/public/data/filename.xlsx?raw=true"
df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(excel_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need just to upgrade pandas version

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```