# Django: Read Uploaded Excel File

Tags: django, excel, pandas, django-views

I have a where users can upload an Excel fie, and am able to call the file in my views.py like so:

```
def create_chart(request):

    # How I get Excel file:    
    file = File.objects.get(id=1).file

    content = file.read()

    # excel.read_data is a custom function I wrote using pandas
    print(excel.read_data(content))
```

Here is what that read_data function actually does:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_data(file, sheetname=0):
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname, engine='xlrd')

    return(df)
```

However, when I run my code I get the following error message:

> Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42950045/5476782

Comment: try passing "file" into `read_data` instead of "content"